# Concatenate in Sequential KERAS U-NET

Tags: keras, unet-neural-network

I want set up a Keras Sequential Deep UNET, but I dont know how to concatenate
specific layers.

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same', input_shape=(512, 512, 4)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(8, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(classes,(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same'))

model = model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

In a non Sequential Model it would be something like that

```
    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 8, (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    u6 = Dropout(dropout)(u6)
    c6 = conv2d_block(u6, n_filters * 8, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)
```

Comment: U-Nets are not sequential models, it is much easier to implement it with the Functional API.

Comment: Ah ok that is the reason.. But with the functional API I ve got AFAIK no possibility to apply model.predict_classes. I saw workarounds like this (y_prob = model.predict(x) 
y_classes = y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)) but they didnt work for me.

Comment: It should work, you need to be very clear in your question, currently it is too vague on what the actual problem is.